# Pause a slick2D state

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm in trouble for my game.

I've this part of code :

```
game.enterState(SelectionTeam.ID);
l.getKey().reduireMana(c.getKey().getCout());
            ((SelectionTeam)this.game.getState(SelectionTeam.ID)).getSelection().subirComp(c.getKey());
```

where I need to wait the end of the state SelectionTeam to use the method reduireeMana.

But I don't know how to pause a state with slick 2D, I neither can use an observer because SelectionItem already extends a class

If someone could help me it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your gamecontainer and call the method pause() to pause your game. This will freeze your update and render loops until is becomes unpaused. For more information please see the API documentation:

http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/GameContainer.html

You can also check whether the game is currently paused with isPaused().

Comment: thanks for your answer, finaly I decided to use some singletone, it's normal to not be able to share parameters between the state, that's a choice from the creators of the lib from what I read. So I'm cheating, but I needed it;